# Get max logins from user table by year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable 
(
    [Year] int, 
    [Month] int, 
    [User] varchar(255), 
    [Logins] int 
)

INSERT INTO #temptable ([Year], [Month], [User], [Logins])
VALUES (2021, 12, 'Jon', 4), 
       (2021, 12, 'Fred', 5), 
       (2021, 7, 'Jon', 1), 
       (2021, 7, 'Fred', 3), 
       (2022, 12, 'Jon', 9), 
       (2022, 12, 'Fred', 7), 
       (2022, 7, 'Jon', 5), 
       (2022, 7, 'Fred', 1)
```

I need to write a query that returns the last month and the logins for that user. The count is cumulative so I just need the latest month value for each year

So for this table for fred it would be

- 2021, fred, 12, 5
- 2022, fred, 12, 7
- 2021, Jon, 12,4
- 2022, Jon, 12,9

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you having?

Comment: Why are you using a `#tempTable` for what looks like persisted data? And why aren't you using a `date`-typed column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use following query:

```
DECLARE @user varchar(255) = 'Fred'

SELECT [Year], [Month], [User], [Logins]
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY [Month] DESC) N
    FROM #temptable
    WHERE [User]=@user
) T
WHERE N=1
```

If you need all users omit where clause and use user in partitioning:

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], [User], [Logins]
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User], [Year] ORDER BY [Month] DESC) N
    FROM #temptable
) T
WHERE N=1
```

Comment: This works but only gives me one user even if I leave out the where clause

Comment: You would need to include the User in the window partition.

Comment: Answer updated to match question update :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT Year, Month, [User], Sum(Logins) SumLogins
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Year, [User] ORDER BY Month DESC) RowNumber
    FROM #temptable
    GROUP BY Year, Month, [User]
)
SELECT Year, Month, [User], SumLogins
FROM cte
WHERE Rownumber=1
AND [User] = 'Fred'
```